Finding out input/base tables of DBT workflow from DBT-generated JSONs
We use BigQuery along with DBT, and we having a hard time which tables are generated by DBT, and which tables are already present and given as input to DBT.
I'm trying to programmatically determine the input tables for all DBT model using the JSON files generated by DBT. Specifically, I have JSON files that represent the workflow, but I'm struggling to filter out the input tables from them.
The JSON artifacts i have include, catalog.json, manifest.json.
I am new to DBT and not sure if this problem can be solved using any DBT resources out of the box without doing some JSON manipulations. Can anyone suggest approaches to get the input/base tables that DBT considers.
